# How do I install a cygwin package from the command line?

Tags: installation, cygwin

I can install a cygwin package when I first install cygwin, but is there something like:

```
cyginstall git
```

kind of like **apt-get**?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to use `setup.exe` w/o the GUI:

```
setup.exe -q -n -N -d -R c:\cygwin -s http://yourFavoriteMirror \ 
-l c:\localPackageDir -P  <comma-separated list of packages to install>
```

This is from [cygwin mailing list](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-01/msg00598.html) (and follow up post)

Comment: Awesome.  @giant_squid's answer is helpful, but this one deserves the check mark.

Answer (score 13):

This question was already asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/41093/installing-cygwin-packages-from-the-command-line). Answer:

```
wget http://apt-cyg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/apt-cyg
chmod +x apt-cyg
mv apt-cyg /usr/local/bin/
apt-cyg install bc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run setup.exe again and add/remove package, as well as the first time ;)